# When, in a custom module, you add a subitem to the top menu in the back-end, is it possible to insert in image alongside the title?

Tags: magento-1, adminhtml, xml, configuration, backend

I'm trying to add in an image next to a dropdown item, alongside the title. Is this possible? I've seen it being done with items in the sidebar under `System > Configuration` before, but never in the top menu. Being able to do something like this would be great, for example:

```
<menu>
    <system>
        <children>
            <example>
                <title><img src="foo.png" />Example</title>
                <action>adminhtml/example/index</action>
            </example>
        </children>
    </system>
</menu>
```

Obviously that's not going to work, so any pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to the title like below

```
<menu>
        <custom_module module="custom_module" translate="title">
        <title><![CDATA[<span class="custom_module">Custom Module</span>]]></title>
```

And then add a adminhtml layout file to add some css to add the image to your menu item.

**Update:**

Ok so it looks like this only worked for me because I have an extension installed that overwrites `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu::getMenuLevel` and updates line 301 to not have the `$this->escapeHtml` wrapper on the label.

```
            . $this->escapeHtml($item['label']) . '</span></a>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the HTML gets output as plain text.

Comment: Fair point, I must have missed something, will let you know if I find it.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: I've updated my answer @Thierry

Comment: Ah, well, that's not going to be a viable solution for me then. I guess that answers my question. Thanks for the information and your time!

Comment: With that in mind, i'd probablly do it with an observer and use preg_replace, would that be an option?